# Query For Top 5 product and Showroom based on discount

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table **l_sales** and it contains 
**Product_id, showroom, discount**
Columns
.I want only top 5 showrooms based on discount and one showroom can sell multiple products and I want top 5 showroom's top 5 products based on discount..
How to achieve this?
Eg:
Showroom|Product_id|Discount
A.                  Soap.          90
A.                  Pen.             60
B.                   Pen.           70
C.                 Pencil.         40
D.                 Cake.           60
E.                  Chocolate.  50

The result would be
Showroom|Product_id|Discount
A.                  Soap.          90
A.                  Pen.             60
B.                   Pen.           70
C.                 Pencil.         40
D.                 Cake.           60
 Here we are getting A twice because it's selling two products and it's discount must be greater than others

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results so it is clear what YOU mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the analytical function as follows:

```
SELECT SHOWROOM, Product_id, DISCOUNT 
  FROM (SELECT T.*, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SHOWROOM ORDER BY DISCOUNT DESC) AS RN 
          FROM (SELECT T.*, 
                       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY S DESC) DR 
                  FROM (SELECT T.*,
                               SUM(DISCOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY showroom) S
                          FROM l_sales T) T) 
          WHERE DR <= 5)
 WHERE RN <= 5
```